# Place feature metathesis

Tags: phonology, historical-linguistics, metathesis

Familiar cases of metathesis involve segments changing places, but metathesis can also operate at the subsegmental level, affecting individual features. I'm specifically interested in metathesis of POA features, like the following examples:

- German *finster* "dark, gloomy" < * *θimster* (edit: this is doubtful as a case of feature metathesis, see jknappen's comments)
- Colloquial Hebrew *maʃaz* "massage" < *masaʒ*

Questions:

1. What are some other examples of this process? It's difficult to find data as this type of metathesis seems to be rare and not much studied.
2. Are there any studies that deal specifically with POA feature metathesis -- e.g. examining its typology, which features do and don't undergo metathesis under which kinds of circumstances, etc.?
3. As a bonus question, are there any attested cases of voicing metathesis (e.g. *tab* > *dap*)? I'm aware that this shows up in child language acquisition errors, but beyond that?

Comment: Interesting. The Hebrew example reminds me of something I read about restrictions on Arabic triliteral roots: roots like sh-m-s are permitted, but roots like s-m-sh do not exist.

Comment: I think the German example can explained without invoking feature metathesis.

Comment: @jknappen How so?

Comment: @TKR: The long explanation can be found in Grimms Wörterbuch (in German) here: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GF04517#XGF04517. Summarized: The alternation th/f is not unprecedented and not conditioned by a following m. The ms is assimilated to ns. Both are natural processes.

Comment: Here's a similar example in Arabic: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/15354/metathesis-linguistic-notation

Answer (score 2):

In Greek declensions there are a couple examples of metathesis quantitatis which is simply vowel length swapping.

Within the second declension we have the Attic declension which consists of nouns like νεώς or λεώς. Originally these forms had long stem vowel and a typical short thematic vowel. Due to a regular sound change the lengths of the vowels changed places.

νηός > νεώς

ληός > λεώς

This is seen throughout the whole paradigm. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greek_grammar_(tables)#Attic_second_declension)

There is quantitative metathesis happening also in the third declension, in the genetive of nouns like βασιλεύς or πόλις.

The standard Attic genetive is  βασιλέως and  πόλεως whilst the Homeric Greek yields βασιλῆος and πόληος.

References:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantitative_metathesis

*A Greek Grammar for Colleges*, Herbert Weir Smyth

*Gramatyka grecka,* Marian Auerbach, Marian Golias

Comment: Greek quantitative metathesis is an interesting (and to my knowledge unparalleled) phenomenon, but I'd say it's quite different from consonantal POA feature metathesis.

Comment: If I am not mistaken a kind of quantitative metathesis happened also during the developments in Common Slavic period. It was connected to the loss of the Slavic "semivowels" (I am not sure what is the English term, in Polish, in Slavic lingustics we use term "jer"; the symbols used are <ь> and <ъ>)

Comment: That's interesting, as I've been looking for parallels to Greek QM for a while. Do you know anywhere I could read more about it?

Comment: It turns out I was mistaken. The case I was talking about is merely a case of compensatory lengthening which accompanies the loss of aforementiond jer vowels, not a QM.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [Ultan's typological study](http://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED091937.pdf) for an overview, and [the metathesis database](http://metathesisinlanguage.osu.edu/database.cfm) for a few examples. I'm extremely skeptical about the prospects for finding a general case where just place features are moved but not voicing and manner, but place is certainly relevant as a conditioning factor.

Comment: Thanks, I'd looked through Ultan's dissertation without finding examples of place feature metathesis; I didn't know about the metathesis database, but will check that out.

Comment: On page 19, something similar to the Hebrew example is discussed: in some French dialects and creoles in Dominica, /s/ followed by /ʃ/ in the same syllable is subject to metathesis, resulting in /ʃ...s/ (example: French /sɛʃ/ "sèche" corresponds to Agde /ʃɛs/). Of course, it is not possible to distinguish this from ordinary metathesis, since the voicing and manner are identical between  the two consonants.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't direct evidence, but this paper mentions several proposed etymologies that make use of feature metathesis: [Feature metathesis and the change of PIE *du̯ to Classical Armenian -rk (Diachronica 2013)](http://www.academia.edu/6375253/Feature_metathesis_and_the_change_of_PIE_du_to_Classical_Armenian_-rk_Diachronica_2013_), by Jessica DeLisi

The only example of possible *place* feature metathesis mentioned is on page 481, and the evidence is ambiguous between that and a simple segmental metathesis.

However, there are some interesting examples in it of "aspiration anticipation," which could be regarded as a kind of metathesis, where an aspirated consonant or the segment /h/ is lost in the middle of a word, but the start of the word receives compensatory aspiration. Here's one of them:

> PIE *h<sup>1</sup>eu̯s “to burn” became Greek *heúō* “to burn, scorch” with unexpected rough breathing compared to Sanskrit *oṣati* “burns”. Aspiration
>   anticipation is quite common in Greek in words with internal *-s- >
>   Pre-Homeric *-h-.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following two examples from German count ...

- Sybille /zy:bɪlə/, a given name coming from the classical name Sibylle /zi:bʏlə/. The rounding is swapped between the first and second vowel while other features (like length and tenseness) are kept.
- Popular mispronounciation of Libyen as "Lübien". Again a vowel rounding swap.

Comment: I think these are spelling pronunciations, resulting from a purely orthographic fluctuation between y and i.

Comment: @fdb: I think they aren't. An unstressed ü is that uncommon in German that the speakers unconsciously want to correct "that mistake".

Comment: I don't understand your transcriptions -- what do I and Y stand for?

Comment: @TKR: It is kind of ASCII-IPA. I is small capital I (as in the English word f**i**t) and Y is small capital Y (as in the German word Gl**ü**ck)

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting. What do you mean by length being retained, though?

Comment: @TKR: the vowel in the first syllable (of both examples) is both longer than the one in the second syllable.