# metathesis linguistic notation

Tags: phonology, phonetics

znƷæbil /Ʒnzæbil/   Ginger

/znƷæbil/   /Ʒnzæbil/ 
/nærƷin/    /ræanƷin/ 
/fænilæh/   /fælinæh/ 
 /Ʒenzir/   /znƷir/

this is the data could you plz help me? 
can you help me to write the metathesis rule for this data? 
I thought that this rule is right 
/VC/----[CV] / three consecutive Cs

Comment: I don't think there is a rule. As far as I know, this is sporadic cross-dialectal variation.

Comment: It looks like this is Arabic, right? In that case, the etymology suggests that /zanjabīl/ is the original form, and /janzabīl/ the metathesized form. You may be interested in this question: [Place feature metathesis](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/15227/place-feature-metathesis)

Comment: You need to provide more data because from one example, we wouldn't be able to infer what it is that triggers metathesis in that language.

Comment: yes, it is Arabic.

Comment: /znƷæbil/ /Ʒnzæbil/
/nærƷin/ /ræanƷin/
/fænilæh/ /fælinæh/
/fælsæfh/ /fælfæsh/
/Ʒenzir/ /znƷir/
 this is the data could you plz help me?